# Does reaction of alkali and alkaine earth metals' reaction with water an acid-base reaction?

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism

In my chemistry notes the teacher gave me the note that reaction of alkali, alkaline earh metals' reactivity with water, acids(e.g. H2S) increases down the group and bases(e.g.NH3) decreases down the group,

And also I have some doubts that

-alkali metals such as Li first react with water and produce oxides first and those oxides react with water and produce hydroxides as end product, is this true?

-and normally water has H2O molecules, (H3O+,OH- ions at small concentration). And when alkali metals react with water do they react with H2O molecule or H3O+ molecule?, If someone could give me a reaction mechanism of an alkali metal with water?

-do alkli, alkaline earth metals act as bases when reacting with water?

Any help would be most greatfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na and K react with the O-H bond of the water molecule. This removes the H atom that is reduced to an H atom and then to a H2 molecule. It is not an acid/base reaction. It is a redox reaction. Na or K atom is oxidized at the end. No metal oxides are produced as intermediating state.

Alkaline and alkaline earth metals act in the same way.